# facebook url image cache is not working i am geting that image from youtube api with get method

Tags: facebook, image, caching, youtube, youtube-api

Facebook image cache works on meta tags so i was given meta tags 
So i am trying to append to head part it was done but image cache not working..

Here is the code :

```
$("head").append('<meta property="og:type" content="article" />

<meta property="og:title" content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" /> 

<meta property="og:description" content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />

<meta property="og:image"content="'+item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url+'"/>');
```

Comment: That looks like javascript. Facebook scraper doesn't execute javascript

Comment: Ya its script , Then what is the solution i am getting the data from script only ?

Comment: You have to do it server side

Comment: ya did that thank you